# Как отправить файл в ASP.NET Core MVC через модель?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

У меня появилась необходимость загружать файл вместе с дополнительными данными. Обычно я отправлял данные в контроллер так:

```
public IActionResult(SomeViewModel model)
{
...
return View();
}
```

Можно ли как-то через модель отправить файл? Или надо сделать что-то иное?

Comment: Что значит с дополнительными данными? Просто отдать файл на скачивание можно с помощью наследников [FileResult](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fileresult?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для загрузки файла в Core используйте `IFormFile`.

Неплохой туториал от Метанита: https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/21.3.php